# Update multiple select2 field with laravel, ajax and angularJs

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, ajax, laravel

I have a multiple select2 Select field.
What I want is to add a new value to my select field. (after adding an entry to the database and bind this entry to the select field)

This is my code so far:

Blade template:

```
<div class="form-group {{ ($errors->first('projectTypes')) ? 'has-error' : '' }}">
 <label for="projectTypes" class="col-md-2 control-label">{{ trans('project/project.fields.projectTypes') }}</label>
 <div class="col-md-9">
     {!! Form::select('projectTypes[]',
        $projectTypes,
        ($project->projectTypes()->count() > 0) ? $project->projectTypes->lists('id')->toArray() : (isset($projectType)) ? $projectType->id : '',
        ['id' => 'projectTypes', 'class' => 'form-control', 'ng-model' => 'projectTypes', 'multiple' => 'multiple'])
      !!}
      <span id="helpBlock" class="help-block">{{ $errors->first('projectTypes') }}</span>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-1">
    <i class="fa fa-plus-square-o fa-2" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#addProjectType"></i>
  </div>
```

The `<i>` tag toggles the modal. In the modal window I have an input field and a button (it works!):

```
<input ng-model="name" id="addProjectType" class="form-control" type="text" name="name" placeholder="Projekttyp">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-embossed" ng-click="addProjectType(name)" data-dismiss="modal">Save changes</button>
```

So if I click on the button this will trigger a function in my angularJS code (this works!).
This is my angularJS Code:

```
$scope.projectTypes = [];
$scope.addProjectType = function(name) {
    $http.post('/ajax/projecttype/addprojecttype', {
        name: name
    }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        $scope.projectTypes.push(data);
    });
}
```

This do an ajax call to my laravel php function (this works!):

```
public function addProjectType(Request $request, Sentinel $sentinel) {
    $name = $request->get('name');
    $projectType = new ProjectType;
    $projectType->name = $name;
    $projectType->slug = $projectType->strSlug($name);
    $this->created_by = $sentinel::getUser()->id;
    $this->updated_by = $sentinel::getUser()->id;
    $projectType->saveModel($request);
    return Response::json($projectType, self::$OK);
}
```

But although I have declared my select field `(ng-model="projectTypes")`
and I declared the `$scope.projectTypes` and push the new Object to the `$scope.projectTypes` after the ajax call the select field won't update.

What am I doing wrong here?